# "Access is denied" when copying text file to printer UNC path

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

We have a new server running Server 2008 R2.  We also have a "DOS-based" program that prints directly to the UNC path of a print share.  With the new server, we are unable to print from this program.  According to support, the program's printing works in the same way as if we were to do a "copy mytextfile.txt \\myserver\myprinter".  When we try to run this command in DOS, we get "Access is denied".  Support is saying that this is why the DOS program is not able to print.  I have tried granting all permissions on the printer to the appropriate users (under Security of the printer properties) but that did not work.  Is there a policy setting that would cause this to be denied?

Comment: Adding the user to the "Print Operators" group fixes the issue.  I would still like to know what policy is affecting this.  Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the exact problem. I finally found out why. Standard users do not have write permission to the spool directory (c:\windows\system32\spool\printers). Once I gave the Users group write permissions to this directory, UNC printing started working.

Comment: Sweet -- that was it!  Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: How does one grant access to the Users group?